# Check if row value match one of values in a list, then assign 1/0 in a new column

Tags: python, pandas

How can I create a new column in a pandas dataframe by following these conditions?

if column '`Ex`' match with one of the elements in this list `l=['cnn', 'nba', 'agi', 'apple']` then:

Create a new column, `S`, having value `1` for those elements in the list above.

For example:

Original dataframe:

```
Ex

cnn
dog
mine
agi
```

Output expected:

```
Ex          S

cnn         1
dog         0
mine        0
agi         1
```

I would approach the problem as follows:

```
df['S']=df['Ex'].apply(lambda x: any([k in x for k in l]))
```

to check if a row matches (I do not want a 'contains' condition) one of the value within `l`. I do not know how to assign values 1 or 0, but I think adding an if statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just do `isin`

```
df['S']=df['Ex'].isin(l).astype(int)
```